# Why i have this error "Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0" when i try to download a document in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to download document and i have probleme with the last instruction because it generate an error "Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0" :

```
const getDocumentById = (req, res, next) => {
     const documentTitle = req.params.dtitle;
     const documentName = documentTitle + '.pdf';
     const documentPath = path.join('uploads', 'documents','admin' , documentName);
     console.log(documentPath);
     fs.readFile(documentPath, (err, data) => {
         if (err) {
              return next(err);
         }
         res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
         res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachement; filename="' + documentName + '"' );
         res.send(data);
     });
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readFile` reads the content of the file as `utf-8` encoded text by default ([see docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)). You could set the encoding to `buffer` but the better approach would be to just use `res.sendFile` ([see docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile))

```
const getDocumentById = (req, res, next) => {
     const filepath = path.join(
         'uploads', 'documents', 'admin', req.params.dtitle + '.pdf');
     res.sendFile(filepath, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition': `attachement; filename="${req.params.dtitle}.pdf"`
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but i still have a small error when i use your method "path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile" and i think the path is exact, here is the structure of my little project : the controller is here './backend/controllers/documents-controllers.js' and document are here './backend/uploads/documents/admin/documentName.pdf'

Comment: I think you should use double / every time it appears, also do include the directory. Path should be like //backend//uploads <- like this, and if not, also try using __dirname

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this in here as I encountered this error when using **nestjs** I had **responseType** set to **json** so it was attempting to parse the response that came in as a json, I changed it to **buffer** and it was able to grab the pdf document.